# Stop WordPress from creating unneeded pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating a landing page in WordPress and I've got an issue.

I've got a custom post type (that's an image), that is displayed via carousel and when clicked opens another web-site in a new tab. Problem is that WordPress generates page for every new page, should it be custom post type page or just basic post page.

I'm using only my main page on web-site so I don't want user to somehow access those pages, cause they basically display nothing.

How can I disable this feature and make WordPress redirect user to main page, if he is somehow trying to access this post pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using only main page and your post pages show nothing (I mean they generate 404 error) you can redirect visitors to home page. In this purpose you can use plugin like this one: [All 404 Redirect to Homepage](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/all-404-redirect-to-homepage/)

Comment: No, they don't show 404. By saying "they show nothing" I mean that I didn't configured them in the template so they display like only header and footer.

Comment: Look please at your body class when you open custom post.   Even if You see header and footer it can be a 404 error and then there will be a class added to body: "error404".  One more thing: when you register custom post type add in $args: 'publicly_queryable'  => false.

Comment: No, it's not 404. You can see it yourself - http://glebgrg4.bget.ru/members/дмитро-фурчак-copy-3/.

I register custom post type with plugin, so I can't add this command.

Comment: Can you tell me name of this plugin?

Comment: If you want to redirect from /members/post-name to your homepage or other page you can use some other redirection plugin (for example [this one](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) )and add there a new redirection using Regex. Your source URL should be: ^/members/.*

Comment: Plugin name is "Custom Post Types UI". Is there a way to disable this feature? To stop WordPress creating this pages?

Comment: I think it's not possible. You can only make redirection.